# how to draw a bitmap and call it back when u need it in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I am using the bitmap data to save choices of the user in my game...but I came across a problem in it... I can ask the bitmap to draw an image...

```
                circle_clk = new circle_big;
                addChild(cicle_clk);
                circle_clk.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cir_bitmap);
                function cir_bitmap (mEvent:MouseEvent) {
                bmpdata= new BitmapData (300, 300); 
                bmp = new Bitmap (bmpdata);
                addChild (bmp);
                bmpdata.draw(circle_clk);
                            }
```

but now I need to ask it bring back this image at the end of the game... how would I do this? how can I draw a bitmap, temporarily remove it from the stage and bring it back when I need it..plus how can I know if it really took an image?..can somebody help me with it please?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line to an outer context such as the class:

```
bmpdata= new BitmapData (300, 300);
```

Then using your code:

```
circle_clk = new circle_big;
addChild(cicle_clk);
circle_clk.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cir_bitmap);
function cir_bitmap (mEvent:MouseEvent) { 
    bmp = new Bitmap (bmpdata);
    addChild (bmp);
    bmpdata.draw(circle_clk);
}
```

If you need to remove the bitmap and add it later, just move it off the stage (change the X coordinate for example) and then place it back where needed when you need the image back in view.

Comment: but I am going to have a lot of these......that's going to be quite messy...plus it will be running a lot of things at once won't it?

Comment: @user1932905 How is it messy? Theyre off the screen. I do it in many of my games. You could always just keep the RGB values rather than the bitmap object but I dont think that will help.